# Count of distinct values with several criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I want to be able to count distinct values with several criteria. As presented here below on the screenshot, I would like to know, how many POs do I have per month depending on the PO type (service or material).

***Initial data:***

[image]

***Desired result:***

[image]

All the data is in text format.The difficulty is that the initial data table will be updated every month (I will be adding lines), so the formula has to consider possible updates. Pivot table will not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I'm offering involves one helper column, but you'll be able to use it quite flexibly. I make the following assumptions:

1. You can add columns to your original table
2. The table starts in cell A1

**Steps:**

1. Convert your data range into a dynamic excel table (select the range, press Ctrl+t, tick "Table Has Headers" - you get a blue table as a result). This way if you add more data, formulas will drag themselves down.
2. type "HELPER" into cell D1, and "Number of POs" into cell E1 - this will create 2 new columns (they should turn blue like the rest of table)
3. paste this formula into cell D2:

   ```
   =[@[Month/Year]]&[@[Mate/Serv]]
   ```
4. Paste this formula into cell E2:

   ```
    =SUMPRODUCT(
           (  [HELPER]=[@[Month/Year]]  &  [@[Mate/Serv]]  )  / 
           COUNTIFS([Month/Year],[Month/Year],
                    [Mate/Serv],[Mate/Serv], 
                    [PO No.],[PO No.]
                    )
           )
   ```
5. Add a pivot table, put Number of POs into values area, it will sum values by default.

As in this picture:

[image: pic1]

6. Right-click inside the values area, select Summarise Values By.. => MAX (as in second picture below).

[image: pic2]

You will see that values in pivot have changed.

this way you won't have to manually maintain the header in your summary table as pivot table will pick up any new entries/months.

**IF YOU WANT TO STICK TO YOUR ORIGINAL DESIGN:**

The same formula can be used (with minor change to add table name to column names), but it still needs the table and helper - follow steps 1-3. Make sure you're set up is as in picture below:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
        (  Table2[HELPER]=H$1&$G2    )  /
        COUNTIFS(Table2[Month/Year],Table2[Month/Year],
                            Table2[Mate/Serv],Table2[Mate/Serv],
                            Table2[PO No.],Table2[PO No.]
                            )
            )
```

[image: pic3]

If anyone would like to change my formula to avoid creating a helper, please do.

I created a dummy table so your results won't be like mine.

**How to test:**

- Copy your data on a new sheet
- Go to Data menu ribbon => Remove Duplicates
- Pivot the remainder
- Put *met/serve* into rows, *month/year* into columns, Helper into Values.

That will give you a count you should expect.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in Columns J:L, you can add a helper column in M, entering this formula in M2 and dragging down:

```
=COUNTIF(J:J,J2)
```

Then, assuming your desired result table is in columns N:P enter this formula in O2:

```
=COUNTIFS($K:$K,O$1,$L:$L,$N2,$M:$M,">0")-MAX((COUNTIFS($K:$K,O$1,$L:$L,$N2,$M:$M,">1")-1),0)
```

You can then drag this cell over to column P and drag them both down.

This also assumes you Desired result table headers are formatted as text as well.

Comment: Jacob, interesting approach, but try duplicating the data table rows, see what happens. Not that i know better, so far haven't come up with much. just saying.

Comment: Ah, you're right. It seems a data filter would be best if possible.